# How can I tell the differences between male and female villagers?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I wanna breed my villagers but I cant find a female villager.

Do they have any notable differences in the way they look? How can I spawn the different genders of villager?

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Answer (score 8):

Villagers in Minecraft (like most other mobs) have no concept of gender. Any villager can breed with any other villager to produce a villager child, as long as there are enough beds.